# Rails Ajax 'Uphold/Like' Button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I can't figure out why my 'Uphold(Like)' button doesn't work.

My app is a kind of Q&A web site, named 'KnowledgeSprout'.
And I appended 'like' feature, named 'uphold', like StackOverFlow's useful button.

The code are below.
It look like counting up is working, but the image can't turn to red dynamically.

UpholdController.rb

```
class UpholdsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @uphold = Uphold.create(user_id: current_user.id, knowledge_sprout_id: param
s[:knowledge_sprout_id], answer_id: params[:answer_id], review_id: params[:revie
w_id], product_review_id: params[:product_review_id])
    @knowledge_sprouts = KnowledgeSprout.find(params[:knowledge_sprout_id])
  end
end
```

And KnowledgeSproutController.rb

```
class KnowledgeSproutsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @knowledge_sprout = KnowledgeSprout.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @q = Restaurant.ransack(params[:q])
    if params[:q].present?
      @restaurants = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
    end
    @answers = Answer.where(ks_id: params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new
    ahoy.track "ks_show", id:  params[:id]
  end
end
```

Here's knowledege_sprout.html.slim

```
.upholds
  = render partial: "uphold", locals: {knowledge_sprout: @knowledge_sprout}
```

_uphold.html.slim

```
  - if user_signed_in?
    - if @knowledge_sprout.uphold_user(current_user.id)
      = image_tag("icon_red_heart.png")
      span
        = @knowledge_sprout.upholds_count
    - else
      = button_to knowledge_sprout_upholds_path(@knowledge_sprout.id), id: "uphold-button", remote: true do
        = image_tag("icon_heart.png")
        span
          = @knowledge_sprout.upholds_count
  - else
    - if @knowledge_sprout.uphold_user(current_user.id)
      = image_tag("icon_red_heart.png")
      span
        = @knowledge_sprout.upholds_count
    - else
      = image_tag("icon_heart.png")
      span
        = @knowledge_sprout.upholds_count
```

JS

```
$("#uphold-button").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  $("#uphold-button").html("= j(render partial: 'uphold', locals: { knowledge_sprout: @knowledge_sprout})")
).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
  $("#uphold-button").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

Here's Models.

```
class KnowledgeSprout < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_many :upholds, dependent: :destroy

        def uphold_user(user_id)
          upholds.find_by(user_id: user_id)
        end

        attr_accessor :file
end
class Uphold < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :knowledge_sprout, counter_cache: :upholds_count
  belongs_to :answers, counter_cache: :upholds_count
  belongs_to :reviews, counter_cache: :upholds_count
  belongs_to :product_reviews, counter_cache: :upholds_count
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Also here's `rake routes` results.

```
     knowledge_sprout_upholds POST     (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:knowledge_sprout_id/upholds(.:format)     upholds#create {:locale=>/en|ja/}
      knowledge_sprout_uphold DELETE   (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:knowledge_sprout_id/upholds/:id(.:format) upholds#destroy {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              GET      (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts(.:format)                                  knowledge_sprouts#index {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              POST     (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts(.:format)                                  knowledge_sprouts#create {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              GET      (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/new(.:format)                              knowledge_sprouts#new {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              GET      (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:id/edit(.:format)                         knowledge_sprouts#edit {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              GET      (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:id(.:format)                              knowledge_sprouts#show {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              PATCH    (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:id(.:format)                              knowledge_sprouts#update {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              PUT      (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:id(.:format)                              knowledge_sprouts#update {:locale=>/en|ja/}
                              DELETE   (/:locale)/knowledge_sprouts/:id(.:format)                              knowledge_sprouts#destroy {:locale=>/en|ja/}
```

Any idea? Help me pls...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your upholds method?

Comment: Well, you mean Upholds Model? I'll post that. Besides, I'll post route information.

Comment: I modified and appended some codes. Could you check it out?